# Python: How to retrieve the content of a cell in our game-field?

Tags: python, class, field

Me and my partner, we need to create a game in python. We are total beginners, so sorry if we ask questions that possibly sound very imprudent for Python-Pro´s.

Here is our code to create a field with a range from 7x7:

```
import string 

class board:
   def __init__(self, width):
      self.w = width
      self.board = [[[] for i in range(width)] for b in range(width)]

   def __setitem__(self, coords, val):
      self.board[coords[0]][coords[-1]] = [val]

   def __repr__(self):
      return ' '+'  '.join(list(string.ascii_lowercase[:self.w]))+"\n"+'\n'.join(string.ascii_lowercase[a]+' '.join(str(i) for i in b) for a, b in enumerate(self.board))  

board = board(7)   
board[(3, 3)] = 'X'
```

---

Until now, it works (not perfect, but good enough to go on with it).

I have now several questions. If you don´t mind, you can just answer one of them. We would be very thankful.

1. The title of the columns and lines are letters (a-g), how do i invert them into numbers?
2. What needs to be done, to get the content of a specific 'cell'? e.G. if the cell in 3,3 has the content 'X', how do i get just the 'X'?

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: Its definitely bad practice to name your `objects` the same as their `classes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the item, you have to define __getitem__ method, for your case:

```
class board:
    def __init__(self, width):
        self.w = width
        self.board = [[[] for i in range(width)] for b in range(width)]

    def __setitem__(self, coords, val):
        self.board[coords[0]][coords[-1]] = [val]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        row, col = item
        return self.board[row][col]

    def __repr__(self):
        return ' ' + '  '.join(list(map(str, range(self.w)))) + "\n" + '\n'.join(str(a) + ' '.join(str(i) for i in b) for a, b in enumerate(self.board))


board = board(7)
board[(3, 3)] = 'X'

print(board[(3, 3)])
# ['X']

print('{board!r}'.format(board=board)
```

And you got the board looks like:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0[] [] [] [] [] [] []
1[] [] [] [] [] [] []
2[] [] [] [] [] [] []
3[] [] [] ['X'] [] [] []
4[] [] [] [] [] [] []
5[] [] [] [] [] [] []
6[] [] [] [] [] [] []
```

BTW, why you define the value as a list in __setitem__ ? I also changed the codes for __repr__ to make it represent the number instead of the letters. Actually you should use __str__ method not __repr__ to do this.

Answer (score -1):

For first, with use of function [ord()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord):

```
ord('a') # => 97
ord('g') # => 103
ord("letter of column/row") - ord('a') # will return index of column/row
ord('g') - ord('a') # this will return 6
```

Comment: The identifiers are being directly set as letters in the `__repr__()` method. Using `ord()` to then convert them to numbers seems a bit back-to-front.